# Conditional Rendering not working in React mapped loop

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, if-statement, babeljs

I am trying to use conditional with mapped loop rendering in react but i am receiving errors.
[image]

Here is the code:

```js
const navbarValue = [{"Category":"Home","Status":1},{"Category":"About","Status":0},{"Category":"Contact","Status":0}];
function NavbarActive(props) {
 return  (
  <li className="active"><a href="">{props.Category}</a></li>
 );
};
function NavbarNotActive(props) { 
 return (
  <li><a href="">{props.Category}</a></li>
 );
};
 
function NavbarList(props) {
 return (
    <div className="navbar-wrapper">
 <div className="container">
 <nav className="navbar navbar-fixed-static-top navbar-inverse">
 <div className="container">
 <div className="navbar-header">
 <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
   <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span className="icon-bar"></span>
  <span className="icon-bar"></span>
  <span className="icon-bar"></span>
 </button>
 <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
 </div>
   <div id="navbar" className="collapse navbar-collapse">
   <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
   {navbarValue.map((obj, index) =>
     if (obj.Status) {
     <NavbarActive  key={index} Category ={obj.Category }/>
     }
   <NavbarNotActive  key={index} Category ={obj.Category }/>
 )}
 </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
 </nav>
 </div>
 </div>
 );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <NavbarList  />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Working code without conditional statment:

```js
const navbarValue = [{"Category":"Home","Status":1},{"Category":"About","Status":0},{"Category":"Contact","Status":0}];
function NavbarActive(props) {
 return  (
  <li className="active"><a href="">{props.Category}</a></li>
 );
};
function NavbarNotActive(props) { 
 return (
  <li><a href="">{props.Category}</a></li>
 );
};
 
function NavbarList(props) {
 return (
    <div className="navbar-wrapper">
 <div className="container">
 <nav className="navbar navbar-fixed-static-top navbar-inverse">
 <div className="container">
 <div className="navbar-header">
 <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
   <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span className="icon-bar"></span>
  <span className="icon-bar"></span>
  <span className="icon-bar"></span>
 </button>
 <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
 </div>
 <div id="navbar" className="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
   {navbarValue.map((obj, index) =>
    <NavbarNotActive  key={index} Category ={obj.Category }/>
   )}
   </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
 </nav>
 </div>
 </div>
 );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <NavbarList  />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
 <div id="root"></div>
```

I am using obj.Status as "True" or "False" to indicate if node has to be rendered active or not active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to use `{}` then put `if-else` statement within map body, and return the result.

Write it like this:

```
{navbarValue.map((obj, index) => {
     if (obj.Status) 
         return <NavbarActive  key={index} Category ={obj.Category }/>
     return <NavbarNotActive  key={index} Category ={obj.Category }/>
})}
```

Or use [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
{navbarValue.map((obj, index) => obj.Status ?
        <NavbarActive  key={index} Category ={obj.Category }/>
     :
        <NavbarNotActive  key={index} Category ={obj.Category }/>}
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{navbarValue.map((obj, index) => {
    return (
        (obj.Status) ?
            <NavbarActive  key={index} Category ={obj.Category }/> :
            <NavbarNotActive  key={index} Category ={obj.Category }/>
    )
})}
```

Try this code with ternary operators.